# How to approximate stochastic volatility model with finite-state Markov chain?

Tags: econometrics, time-series, computation, markov-chain, statistics

A common practice when computing solutions to stochastic dynamic optimization problems is to approximate an exogenous forcing process $z_{t+1} = \rho z_t + \sigma \epsilon_{t+1}$ with a finite-state Markov chain, e.g. by Tauchen's or Rouwenhorst's method. What would be a good way to discretize AR(1) process with stochastic volatility?

That is, if the original AR(1)-SV process looks something like this:
$$
\begin{split}
z_{t+1} &= \rho_z z_t + \mathrm{e}^{v_t} \sigma_z \epsilon_{t+1} \\
v_{t+1} &= \rho_v v_t + \sigma_v \eta_{t+1} 
\end{split}
$$
with $\epsilon, \eta$ being independent standard gaussian shocks, my goal is to obtain values $z_i$ and transition probabilities $p_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,\dots,n$) such that the corresponding Markov chain approximates the original continuous-valued process.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a binomial-tree approximation to the process for $z_t$ and then have a different process control the number of steps you take on the tree. This preserves recombining property and it is essentially the method explored in [On the Computation of  Continuous  Time Option Prices Using Discrete Approximations](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2331407) (Amin (1991))

> We  develop  a class of  **discrete, path-independent  models** to 
>   compute prices  of American options  within the Black-Scholes  (1973)
>   framework,  **including  models in which state variables have 
>   time-varying volatility**  functions and models with  multiple  state
>   variables. Time-varying volatility  functions are illustrated with 
>   applications  to term structure models developed by  Vasicek  (1977) 
>   and  Heath, Jarrow,  and Morton  (1988), (1990).  Distinct from 
>   previous  work in the  literature,  the multivariate models suggested
>   in this  paper are consistent with  arbitrarily large, though
>   constant,  covariance functions. Finally,  we compare  and contrast
>   the numerical  accuracy  of a  large  number of models with simulation
>   results.

You could then use a [binomial AR(1) process](http://www2.hsu-hh.de/mathstat/downloads/Folien_09_12_2.pdf) for the number of steps.